# Php - Static function of class named List

Tags: php, list, class, static

I have a class named List, this class has a static method. When I call:

```
List::method();
```

The following error occurs:

```
syntax error, unexpected '::' (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM), expecting '('
```

Does php think I want to call the native function list()? Do I have to rename the class?

Comment: `list` is a PHP reserved word.... because you can't have a classname that matches an existing function or construct

Comment: Got it: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=40790

Comment: Upvoting question because it's a good one for future visitors to reference.

Comment: @MarkBaker you most certainly can, just need to be able to tell the tokenizer to consider it a classname instead of a language construct, with the namespace operator. I'd still not **recommend** doing it, but it's certainly **possible**.

Comment: OK, namespacing aside, it's a reserved word. As OP said List instead of \List, I think I can be forgiven

Comment: I was only objecting to the "you can't have" part  :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no. `list` is not a function, but a [language construct](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php). As such it's a 'reserved word', meaning it will be treated differently by the tokenizer during compilation.

The compiler expects the `list` token to be followed as in the language construct, so with a `(` as it reports. Instead you're feeding it the scope operator, meaning it gets confused. Easiest solution is to rename your class (it's overly generic anyway) or to prevent namespace conflicts, either by putting the class `List` in your own namespace, or by explicitly referencing the global namespace:

```
\List::method();
```

This should work as well from PHP 5.3 upwards - it tells the compiler to look into the global namespace, where it automatically expects a class name after the backslash.

Comment: I came across this issue (again) and stumbled on your answer in the process of searching for bugs/feature requests and the like. In discussing this with in the PHP room here, I tested this code. Your suggestion to use namespace resolution does not work in 5.4. It throws the expected error, `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'List' (T_LIST), expecting identifier (T_STRING) in ...`

Comment: You're right, it's also broken in 5.5. Regrettably building a proper tokenizer isn't part of anyone's job in the PHP team, so indeed it's going to remain impossible for a while to use the overly long list of reserved words as identifier names.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, PHP tries to call the native function 
T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM means unexpected double colon, so when you rename the class everything should be allright